# I want Ubuntu command results to come out in one shot

Tags: ubuntu, command

I hope the results of the command executed in Ubuntu are all at once, as in the title.

But it comes with a gif file.

What should I do ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Musoh.gif)

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean, and the GIF file doesn't clarify anything at all, in fact it seems totally unrelated to your issue.

Comment: @KenY-N Sorry I do not speak English well:) This is what I wanted to ask. If you look at the gif file, you will see the result when you hit the command on the first monitor. However, this is not the case when you hit the command on the second monitor.

Comment: Sorry, but the GIF is too small to see what the difference between the two are; all I can see is that the colours are different and that one terminal scrolls faster than the other. Do you have different [`LS_OPTIONS` or aliases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86708/46316)?